# Framework agnostic DI registration at runtime

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am creating a custom `ASP.NET Core` `Model Binder` (though this question could be applied to other situations) to be able to `DI` resolve my `View Model` without my `Controller` knowing what the `View Model` depends on.

This is the `CreateModel` method:

```
    protected override object CreateModel(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var serviceProvider = bindingContext.HttpContext.RequestServices;

        return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(bindingContext.ModelType);
    }
```

Problem is that this requires me to register my `ViewModels` like this:

```
services.AddTransient<HomeViewModel, HomeViewModel>();
```

Well, I want to avoid that registration. Can I in my `CreateModel` method determine if the `bindingContext.ModelType` is 1) already registered and 2) a `class` (vs an `interface` or some other `type`), and if so, to register it to itself before trying to resolve it?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that registration?

Comment: @MarkSeemann Because it is unnecessary work. However, the "why" is not important... what is important is the "how".

Comment: This sounds like you are tearing down your container and building it back up piecemeal. It sounds like you want to pull out the type and re-register the type without knowing the final class. I don't think this it is possible.

Comment: @lrb No, don't want to re-register it. Only want to register it if it hasn't been registered yet.

Comment: You could use a container.HasType()

Comment: In the context of my `CreateModel` could you throw up an answer implementing your comment?

Comment: That is why I said piecemeal. I have only registered everything, tore down everything, and re-registered everything again all being done outside the scope of a controller class. It sounds like you are looking to do this in your controller class without referencing your DI container. I think you would be required to reference the DI backing in your controller directly or indirectly. Take the class out and re-register, however, you would still need to know the final class for this.

Comment: @lrb I think you're missing the point. 1) I am not doing this in my controller, but in the Model Binder 2) The final class is the same as the initial class. Please look at my example code.